# .NET Core / .NET 6: Creating a TLB or DLL that can be added as reference in VBA

Tags: excel, dll, com, tlb

I am trying to do basically what it says in the title: I have created a class library (dll) using .NET 6.0 and I would like to add that as a reference in an Excel/Access VBA document. I diligently followed the steps here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com

No matter what I try, I cannot add the resulting dll as a reference in Excel. I just keep getting the message: 'Can't add reference to the specified file'.

A bit more info: I am able to create the Assembly.comhost.dll file, and I think I have done everything correctly, but no joy.

This is rather frustrating, as doing this in .NET Framework is but a click of a couple of checkboxes. In .NET Core (.NET 6) It seems to be a bit of a nightmare. Also, being able to create a tlb from the dll was always a perfect confirmation that you would be able to add your reference in Excel.

ANY help is most welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, much was lost with COM support during the .NET Framework to .NET Core3/5/6 translation for no apparent reason... From Excel you must add a reference to a "type library". That type library can be in a .tlb file or in a .dll if that .dll contains an embedded. .tlb. Have you built and embedded a.tlb in the .dll (it's possible starting with .NET 6 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com#embedding-type-libraries-in-the-com-host)?

Comment: Hi Simon. The issue is, in order to build a TLB that I can then embed into the .NET 6 DLL, i will have to create the DLL in .NET Framework, at that point, might as well create the complete solution there rather than bothering with going back to Core. Also, the whole reason why I am doing this is to 'move forward' with .NET 6 since it is supposed to be the future. Am I missing something?

Comment: So what's your question exactly? A type library is a COM concept, you can create a .tlb using an .idl file and the midl compiler, ie: you don't *have to* use .NET Framework.

Comment: My question is as stated above. However, if you have a link that explains how to create an IDL file and compile that, so that I can then embed that into my .NET 6 DLL, then I would be happy to investigate that. I am still a bit frustrated at how much additional work is involved in doing something I used to be able to do in 2 clicks. Thanks for you r answers!

Comment: Yes, .NET 3/5/6 add more work to support COM (and BTW you also lost the "Any Cpu" coolness...) . The tlb subject is too vast to answer exactly. You can create an .idl from scratch and use midl.exe to compile it. But .idl is quite difficult, so you can use the OleView tool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer and look at all existing one. You can also build a COM dll with .NET Fx, export it with tlbexp or regasm and look at it with OleView too. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/creating-a-type-library

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. You confirm my fears. Thank you so much for your input! I'll look into IDL, but I might as well just resign to using .NET Fx for these types of projects. Thanks again! I'll leave this up in case there are additional developments in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the tutorial you hav ementioned, ther is a topic "Register the COM host for COM". here a file named "**ProjectName.comhost.dll**" is used to register the assembly to the registry as a COM type library.
After doing this, i could the assembly in VBS with the fowing conde:

```
set projectObject = CreateObject("ProjectNamespace.ProjectClass")
newValue = projectObject.ComputeNewValue("abc")
```

Right now, I was not able to establish a reference to that type library in my Excel 2016, **but the code sample works in VBA as well**.

Answer (score 0):

I could also in VBA

```
Set projectObject = CreateObject("COMServer.Server")
MsgBox projectObject.ComputePi()
```

with this repository : https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/extensions/COMServerDemo

But that works only with Registered COM not with RegFree COM (Go check README).

*Not every component is a suitable candidate for use under Reg-Free COM. A component is not considered suitable if any of the following are true:*

- The component is an out-of-process (ActiveX EXE) server. Only DLLs
  are supported.
- The component is a system component or part of the operating system,
  such as XML, Data Access, Internet Explorer, or DirectX® components.
  For example, you should not attempt to isolate components such as
  Microsoft XML (MSXml.dll) or Microsoft Internet Controls
  (SHDocVw.dll). These components are either part of the operating
  system, or can be installed with a separate redistributable package.
- The component is part of an application, such as Microsoft Office.
  For example, you should not attempt to isolate components such as the
  Microsoft Word Object Model or Microsoft Excel Object Model. These
  two components are part of Office and can only be used on a machine
  that has the full Office product installed on it.
- The component is intended for use as an add-in or a snap-in, such as
  an Office add-in or a control in a Web browser. Such components
  typically require some kind of registration scheme defined by the
  hosting environment that is beyond the scope of the manifest itself.
  The other problem is an arbitrary application may not be designed to
  recognize isolated components, as it probably doesn't have a way to
  reference your component through a manifest.
- The component manages a shared physical or virtual system resource.
  For example, it could manage some kind of data connection shared
  between multiple applications or a device driver for a print spooler.

Source : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cc08575d-3506-4a0f-a9e2-f23c2162ad38/using-net-excel-addin-with-registrationfree-com?forum=innovateonoffice

**But I couldn't find a way to add it in Excel as a reference.**